# Digital Crown - Moving Images?

Tags: watchkit

Is it possible to use the Digital Crown to move an Object in my WKnterfaceController?

Something like an Image or an Button?

The only thing i found was to use it in a PickerView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the digital crown to scroll lists. This is the built in behaviour of lists. If you place your image or the buttons in a list, you can move it.